# Is it possible to enable 1 Gbit ethernet on RPi 2, 3, 4?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ethernet-port

By default, it seems that the ethernet port on RPi 2 is 100 Mbit.

Is there a way (via software) to enable 1000 Mbit ethernet?

I also have the same question for RPi 3, and RPi 4.

Comment: The best place is to see the specifications on the RPT/RPF product pages at https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/.  Here they detail the Ethernet connections such as on the 3B+ *Gigabit Ethernet over USB 2.0 (maximum throughput 300 Mbps)*  The quickest throughput so far I've seen (Nov 20) is the Compute 4 board running an external network card https://youtu.be/a-0PeuPINiQ - As this data is readily available (inc many max vs actual articles on the web) I'm voting close on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because data rates readily available via web search and subject to change as new models / adapters tried with software tweaks (e.g. MTU / Jumbo Frames / Kernel Drivers)

Comment: @Andyroo Indeed https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/ shows `Gigabit Ethernet over USB 2.0 (maximum throughput 300 Mbps)`; what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @Andyroo "Available via web search" is true for many many many SE posts, but evil is in the detail. As said before, even in the official spec page https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/?resellerType=home, it is not very explicit: is "Gigabit Ethernet over USB 2.0 (maximum throughput 300 Mbps)" about using an external USB ethernet adapter? Then what about the built-in ethernet cable? It is not written on this page.

Comment: The max through put means you can get a maximum of 300 Mbs though the link - the port follows the Gigabit cabling and electrical standards (OSI Physical Level) https://www.lifewire.com/layers-of-the-osi-model-illustrated-818017 As for external adapters - that depends on the adapter see the video for max throughput

Comment: @Andyroo But what does *"over USB 2.0"* mean? Does this mean we have to use [an external USB/Ethernet adapter](https://www.amazon.fr/UGREEN-Adaptateur-Ethernet-Supporte-Sup%C3%A9rieur/dp/B00MYTSN18)? This is unclear from the official raspberrypi.org page.

Comment: Please research things first - the Pi 3B+ drives it ethernet port via USB 2 internally.

Comment: Of course, @Andyroo, but the wording is not super explicit. I have read blog posts of people having a limited bandwidth with the built-in RPi ethernet socket + much higher bandwidth with an external USB ethernet adapte! See here: https://www.place4geek.com/blog/2017/02/tutoriel-booster-la-vitesse-ethernet-dun-raspberry-pi-3/. So this information *could* have been this.

Comment: @Andyroo: `Via la prise Ethernet du Raspberry PI 3 (en natif) : 94.5 Mbps soit : 11.8 Mo/sec` // `Via la prise Ethernet de l’adaptateur Ethernet en USB 3.0 : 323 Mbps soit : 40,4 Mo / sec`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the Pi4 can do 1 Gbit over the built in ethernet.

Comment: Thank @CoderMike for this answer. Can you add an authorative source to your answer with links? For example https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/?resellerType=home is not very precise ("Gigabit Ethernet over USB 2.0 (maximum throughput 300 Mbps)").

Comment: @CoderMike - That is such a wooly answer that its virtually pointless.  Do you mean physical connection of data speed?  Also the Pi 400 has a Gbit adapter :-)

Comment: @Andyroo The question only asked about Pi2,Pi3 and Pi4.